# Use grep to extract 6 arbitrary digits not starting with 3 binary digits

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

I have received an assignment that i'm struggling with where, somewhat simplified, i need to extract 6 arbitrary digits from a dataset that cannot start with 3 binary digits. I am only allowed to use grep-commands. For example, from this dataset:

```
578696344678
100307548
105768
```

i want to extract these pieces:

```
578696
344678
307548
105768
```

So it is allowed for multiple matches on the same row, and it can start on less than 3 binary digits, but not exactly 3 binary digits. I've fiddled a bit with various regex concepts but so far i only have this base code, because my inexperienced mind can't see any possible approach to separate the binary digits:

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{6\}'
```

Comment: I think that every time you say "binary digits", you just mean "digits" (i.e. 0 to 9)

Comment: [`(?:[01]{3})?(\d{6})` capture group 1](https://regex101.com/r/FG0cB5/1)

Comment: @ctwheels regex101 in PCRE mode is not compatible with grep.

Comment: In your example output, you're printing every 6 digit sequence - the "not starting with 3 digits" thing isn't really relevant, since the first 6 are matched, then you're left with less than 6, so it's not a match.

Comment: @TomFenech Perhaps it was a bit hard to catch, but in the second line the digits started with 100307548 and i wanted the 307548 part. I'll remove the random text to make it a bit more clear. So basically, if a sequence of numbers on a line starts with 3 binary digits (0,1) i want to skip those 3 digits and see if there is another sequence after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it in two steps

```
grep -Po -e '([01]{3})*(\d{6})' | grep -Po '(\d{6})$'
```

First getting the matching digits with/without leading 'binary digits'. Second, the 6 digits at the end.

The same thing without extended RegEx

```
grep -Eo '([01]{3})?([0-9]{6})' | grep -Eo '([0-9]{6})$'
grep -o '\([01][01][01]\)*\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)' | grep -o '\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)$'
```

Comment: This was what i needed, appreciate giving an answer for both regular and extended.

Comment: Note that `-E` enables "extended" regex, so only the last example is "without extended". Also in basic mode (no `-E`) you can still use `{3}` but you have to write `\{3\}`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can use GNU grep, not POSIX grep, you can use a PCRE:

```
$ echo "$txt"
578696344678
100307548
105768

$ echo "$txt" | grep -oP '(?:[01]{3})?\K(\d{6})'
578696
344678
307548
105768
```

GNU grep is the default on Linux but not macOS or BSD.

[Explanation of regex](https://regex101.com/r/d8LI0m/1/)

With POSIX grep, you need to use alteration to find all patterns that are either 9 digits starting with the binary digits or 6 digits and then filter to the desired 6 digits at the end:

```
$ echo "$txt" | grep -Eo '[01]{3}[[:digit:]]{6}|[[:digit:]]{6}' | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{6}$'
578696
344678
307548
105768
```

Answer (score 0):

Your search pattern is correct, you have to use `-o` switch with `grep`:-

```
   -o, --only-matching
          Show only the part of a matching line that matches PATTERN.
```

Comment: This suggestion doesn't produce the desired output.

Comment: `$ grep -o '[0-9]\{6\}' file  
    578696                       
    344678                       
    100307                       
    105768                       
                                 
    $ uname -sro                 
    Linux 2.6.18-419.el5 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! Maybe include the full command in your answer in that case. But still, the "3 digits before" condition isn't considered here - I commented asking the OP to clarify...

Comment: @Yoda My mistake, forgot to add the -o bit to the question since i'm used to  the color coding of grep